# How to make SeekBar segments, and each segment shows different colors?

Tags: java, android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have a project where  the seekbar is to be divided into three segments (not always equal). According to the progress of the slider, each segment will display different colors.

For example, assume that seekbar's maximum value is 100 so...

- progress to 0-10 when first shown in red.
- progress for 10-80 when the first segment is shown in red, the second
  segment display green.
- progress for 80-100 when first shown in red, the second
  segment show green, the third segment shows in yellow.

Is there any way to achieve this?

**The effect chart is as follows:**

[image]

Comment: @Xzying Have you try my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Link...

https://azzits.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/customseekbar/

Full Example Code
https://github.com/azzits/CustomSeekbar

```
int progressBarWidth = getWidth();
int progressBarHeight = getHeight();
int thumboffset = getThumbOffset();
int lastProgressX = 0;
int progressItemWidth, progressItemRight;
for (int i = 0; i < mProgressItemsList.size(); i++) {
    ProgressItem progressItem = mProgressItemsList.get(i);
    Paint progressPaint = new Paint();
    progressPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(progressItem.color));

    progressItemWidth = (int) (progressItem.progressItemPercentage
            * progressBarWidth / 100);

    progressItemRight = lastProgressX + progressItemWidth;

    // for last item give right of the progress item to width of the
    // progress bar
    if (i == mProgressItemsList.size() - 1
            && progressItemRight != progressBarWidth) {
        progressItemRight = progressBarWidth;
    }




    Rect progressRect = new Rect();
    progressRect.set(lastProgressX, thumboffset / 2, progressItemRight,
            progressBarHeight - thumboffset / 2);
    canvas.drawRect(progressRect, progressPaint);
    lastProgressX = progressItemRight;
}
super.onDraw(canvas);
 }
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button btnSeekTo;
private CustomSeekBar seekbar;
private EditText txtSeekProgress;
private ToggleButton btnToogleSeek;

private float totalSpan = 1500;
private float redSpan = 200;
private float blueSpan = 300;
private float greenSpan = 400;
private float yellowSpan = 150;
private float darkGreySpan;

private ArrayList<ProgressItem> progressItemList;
private ProgressItem mProgressItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    seekbar = ((CustomSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar0));
    btnSeekTo = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSeekTo));
    btnToogleSeek = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btnToogleSeek);
    txtSeekProgress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSeekProgress);
    initDataToSeekbar();
    btnSeekTo.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnToogleSeek.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void initDataToSeekbar() {
    progressItemList = new ArrayList<ProgressItem>();
    // red span
    mProgressItem = new ProgressItem();
    mProgressItem.progressItemPercentage = ((redSpan / totalSpan) * 100);
    Log.i("Mainactivity", mProgressItem.progressItemPercentage + "");
    mProgressItem.color = R.color.red;
    progressItemList.add(mProgressItem);
    // blue span
    mProgressItem = new ProgressItem();
    mProgressItem.progressItemPercentage = (blueSpan / totalSpan) * 100;
    mProgressItem.color = R.color.blue;
    progressItemList.add(mProgressItem);
    // green span
    mProgressItem = new ProgressItem();
    mProgressItem.progressItemPercentage = (greenSpan / totalSpan) * 100;
    mProgressItem.color = R.color.green;
    progressItemList.add(mProgressItem);
    // yellow span
    mProgressItem = new ProgressItem();
    mProgressItem.progressItemPercentage = (yellowSpan / totalSpan) * 100;
    mProgressItem.color = R.color.yellow;
    progressItemList.add(mProgressItem);
    // greyspan
    mProgressItem = new ProgressItem();
    mProgressItem.progressItemPercentage = (darkGreySpan / totalSpan) * 100;
    mProgressItem.color = R.color.grey;
    progressItemList.add(mProgressItem);

    seekbar.initData(progressItemList);
    seekbar.invalidate();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSeekTo) {
        String seekProgress = txtSeekProgress.getText().toString().trim();
        if (seekProgress.length() > 0) {
            seekbar.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(seekProgress));
        }
    } else {
        seekbar.setEnabled(btnToogleSeek.isChecked());
    }
 }
```

Xml

```
<yourpackagename.CustomSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/customSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seek_thumb_normal"
    android:thumbOffset="12dp" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do Something Like this

```
public void setProgressBarColor(ProgressBar progressBar, int newColor){ 
    LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) progressBar.getProgressDrawable();
    ClipDrawable d1 = (ClipDrawable) ld.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.progressshape);
    d1.setColorFilter(newColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

}
```

hope it will work for you

Comment: call this method into following Code

Comment: This will affect color of the whole progress bar not individual segments.

Comment: go through this link you will get your Right Answer      https://azzits.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/customseekbar/

Answer (score 0):

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        setProgressBarColor(seekBar,Your color Code );
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
});
```

Comment: How about you edit this in your original answer instead?